# Convert current date + 1 month in accountExpire AD attribut

Tags: php, timestamp

I try to convert current date + 1 month to a final timestamp for Active Directory attribut accountExpire.
But the timestamp returned is wrong if someone can help me. Thanks

```
$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$final = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month', $now));
$dateTime = new DateTime($final);
$timestamp = $dateTime->format('U');

echo $timestamp;
```

Comment: What do you mean wrong?

Comment: i mean the final date is like year 1601...

Comment: Why do you mix 3 different approaches here? One of these function would be enough.

Comment: U can put an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need

```
$timestamp = strtotime('+1 month');
```

I had to look it up, but it turns out that LDAP timestamp is not the same as UNIX timestamp. LDAP timestamp is counted in 100s of nanoseconds and is counted from year 1601. You can easily convert one into another by applying the difference and multiplying by 10000000

```
$UNIXtimestamp = strtotime('+1 month');
$LDAPTimestamp = ($UNIXtimestamp + 11644473600) * 10000000;
```

Comment: I got this output : 1.581848049E+16

Comment: Where did you get this output? Is your system 64bit?

Comment: Yes it's 64bit and i get my output on echo $LDAPtimestamp

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up and changed my answer. Can you try my suggestion above?